# Uploading a file into a github repos via html widget?

Tags: github

Is there any way to make an html widget where a user on my website can upload a file to my github repos?

Answer (score 0):

user upload a file to your server then your server put that file to github repos then commit and push it :D

Comment: problem is that my website is hosted at github pages